# Ito calculus problem

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, itos-lemma

given
 $S^1$ satifying the SDE $\quad dS_{t}^{1}=S_{t}^{1}((r+\mu)dt + \sigma dW_t), \quad S_{0}^{1}=1 $ 

and the safe asset $S_{t}^{0}$  $\quad S_{t}^{0}:=e^{rt} \quad for \quad r\geq 0$

**Q1.**
 how to show that  $\quad Y_t:=log(S_{t}^{1})$ 
 satisfies 
$\quad dY_t=(r+\mu-\sigma^2/2)dt+\sigma d W_t \quad Y=0$,

**Q2.** 
how to find a measure Q equivalent to P (using Girsanov Theorem) such that 
$dS_{t}^{1}=S_{t}^{1}(rt+\sigma d W_{t}^{*})$

I tried the fist part, is the derivation correct?

$\frac{ d S_{t}^{1}}{S_{t}^{1}}=(r+\mu)dt+\sigma dW_t$

$dY=d log(S_{t}^{1})$ 
by Ito 
$d log(S_{t}^{1})=\ \frac{ d S_{t}^{1}}{S_{t}^{1}} + \frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{(S_{t}^{1})^2})(d S_{t}^{1})^2)=$
$=\ \frac{ d S_{t}^{1}}{S_{t}^{1}} + (- \frac{1}{2}  \frac{(\sigma S_{t}^{1})^2)dt}{(S_{t}^{1})^2 }) = 
(r+\mu)dt + \sigma dW_t + (- \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 dt)  =(r+\mu-\sigma^2/2)dt+\sigma dW_t$

I am struggling with the measure change, could anybody help and explain the idea and the next steps?

Comment: I think this doesn't belong to the site because it's too basic for quantitative finance and any QF book would cover in details.

Comment: topic and difficulty are two different matters, right? you were pointing  some Quant Finance books as a source, could you please explain then how this question can be off-topic???

Comment: Why $\frac{ d S_{t}^{1}}{S_{t}^{1}} + (- \frac{1}{2}  \frac{(\sigma S_{t}^{1})^2)}{(S_{t}^{1})^2}) = 
(r+\mu)dt + \sigma dW_t -(\frac{1}{2}  (- \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 ))$?

Comment: a typo, I dropped the dt there either, I corrected the equation

Comment: Then, why $(r+\mu)dt + \sigma dW_t + (- \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 dt)  =(r+\mu+\sigma^2/2)dt+\sigma dW_t$.

Comment: corrected to $(r+\mu-\sigma^2/2)dt+\sigma dW_t$

Comment: I think it's borderline but the question has been improved. @Michal which resources are you using to learn/solve this? That would be a further and needed improvement

Comment: lecture scripts and notes, google, I am analyzing / solving problems and trying to understand the logic behind.  it works for the most of the time

Answer (score 2):

For a time interval $[0,T]$, Girsanov theorem states that given a process $\lambda$ such that process $U$, defined by
$$dU_t = -\lambda_tU_tdW_t, \; U_0=1,$$
is a $P$-martingale, then one can define a new measure $Q$ equivalent to $P$ by
$$\frac{dQ}{dP} = U_T,$$
and a standard Brownian motion under $Q$, $W^\star$, by
$$ dW^\star_t = dW_t + \lambda_tdt.$$
In your case, if we take
$$ \lambda_t = \mu/\sigma \; \forall t \in [0,T],$$
then $U$ is indeed $P$-martingale (no drift)
  and $W^\star$ defined  by
$$ dW^\star_t = dW_t + \mu/\sigma dt$$
is standard Brownian motion under $Q$.

We can now re-write $S^1$ as follows (no Ito):
$$ dS^1_t = (r+\mu)S^1_tdt + \sigma S_t^1 dW_t $$
$$ = rS^1_tdt + \sigma S^1_tdW^\star_t. $$

Finally, note that $Q$ is an interesting measure, a so-called EMM (equivalent martingale measure) with numeraire $S^0$, as it is equivalent to $P$ *and* $S^1/S^0$ (deflated $S^1$) is a $Q$-martingale. Indeed, using Ito-Leibniz, we see that $S^1/S^0$ has no drift under $Q$:

$$ d(S^1_t/S^0_t) = \sigma S^1_t/S^0_t dW^\star_t. $$

Answer (score 1):

For **Q2**, let $\lambda = \mu/\sigma$. Moreover, we define the measure $Q$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ such that
\begin{align*}
\frac{dQ}{dP}\big|_{\mathcal{F}_t} = \exp\Big(-\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2 t - \lambda W_t\Big), \mbox{ for } t \ge 0.
\end{align*}
Then, by Girsanov theorem, $W^*$, where
\begin{align*}
W_t^* = \lambda t + W_t,
\end{align*}
is a standard Brownian motion under the measure $Q$. Furthermore,
under $Q$,
\begin{align*}
dS_t^1 &= S_t^1\big[(r+\mu)dt + \sigma dW_t \big]\\
&= S_t^1(rdt + \sigma dW_t^*).
\end{align*}